# How to combine several input data from items to one (string) variable in ztree?

Tags: ztree

In my experiment, users have the choice between 10 items per round they can select or leave the checkbox emtpy. In the next step, I'd like to create a new variable, e.g. MyInputR1, which holds the values of the previous checkboxes in the right order and as 1 new number.

My approach so far:
a)

- Formatting input data: `f1=format(D11,0.2)`.
- Combining the input data and storing the information in a new variable: `f = f1 + f2 + f3 + ...`.
- Creating the variable `MyInputR1 = stringtonumber(f)`

b) Combining the input data (with values 0 or 1): `MyInputR1 = D11  + D12  + D13 + D14 + ...`

Unfortunately, the logic does not sum up and ztree does not understand what I am trying to do.
Thus my question:

Is it possible to combine / string together input data into 1 new variable, instead of adding it up?

---

Input data: checkbox with values 0 or 1
in total 10 input variables (`D11` - `D110`)
Looking for a variable that e.g. looks like this: `MyInputR1 = 0000011111`

[ztree code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alCEO.png)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others. Do not post your source code on an external site.

Comment: It is not the answer for your question but you can try to keep everything as integers: 
For instance you can define your variable as f = f1 * power(10,0) + f1 * power(10,1) + f2 * power(10,2) ... and then do the comparison.

String variables are relatively new in z-Tree so my feeling is that the applications within them are not as robust as those of numbers.